# Tkinter Linux version of "<Control-Shift-u>"

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, key-bindings

What's the Linux version of `"<Control-Shift-u>"` for keybindings in Tkinter? You might be tempted to think it's exactly that, but, alas, it does not seem to be. For instance, the Linux version of `"<Control-Shift-Tab>"` is `"<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>"`. I've searched and haven't found any documentation for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
from Tkinter import *

def proof(event=None):
    print 'ping'

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
frame.focus_set()
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-KeyPress-U>', proof)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The `u` becomes capitalized because of the shift modifier and you want to capture the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: That works for other letters besides u (I didn't realize that when I asked the question, though), but in Tkinter some other default functionality takes over the keybinding for some reason, allowing pretty much the same Unicode input method I'm wanting, except that it's buggy and can disable your keyboard if you enter the wrong thing.

Comment: Just for reference, I'm binding a ScrolledText widget.

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround. The trick is to use a menu accelerator, like this (similar to what you said, with the capital U): `self.menu_tools.add_command(label="Insert Unicode Character", command=self.enter_code, accelerator="Ctrl+U");`

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for the comments @user2962794 -- I learned something from your question as well.  Does that the letter `u` when caps lock is on though?

Comment: Good insight with the caps lock. It doesn't naturally do anything with ctrl-U (without pressing shift) when the caps-lock is on. Thanks. Very interesting.